# Repeating values with different Ffequencies

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a dynamic range of data I'm trying to repeat with different frequencies in a single column. I'm able to repeat the values with a static formula, however, because the records in `Value` and `Frequency` constantly update with new values and frequencies, I'm trying to write an `ARRAYFORMULA` that will update when `Value` or `Frequency` update.

Data:

```
Value | Frequency

foo   | 3
bar   | 1
baz   | 2
```

Expected output:

```
Value

foo
foo
foo
bar   
baz
baz
```

I think I'm close with this formula (below) where `DATA!A2:A` is the `Value` column and `DATA!B2:B` is the `Frequency` column:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(SPLIT(DATA!A2:A ,",")&",", DATA!B2:B))), ","))
```

However, I cannot get it working correctly.

Comment: What's wrong with your formula? Works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(SPLIT(
 INDIRECT("DATA!A2:A"&COUNTA(DATA!A2:A)), ",")&",", 
 INDIRECT("DATA!B2:B"&COUNTA(DATA!B2:B))))), ","))
```

[image: 0]